# prepared statement of mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have recently shifted from mysql to mysqli , now trying to reformat my codes to mysqli.

Kindly guide me whats wrong with these statements.

Code:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$sample ='sample123'; // these are dummy values
$orecip='admin';      // these are dummy values
$omessage='test';      // these are dummy values
$date = date('Y-m-d'); // these are dummy values
$read='yes';          // these are dummy values
$read1='no';          // these are dummy values
$otitle='test';       // these are dummy values

$insert = $MySQLi_CON->query("INSERT INTO messages (user_from, user_to, title, message, date, user_from_read, user_to_read)
    VALUES($sample, $orecip, $otitle ,$omessage,$date,$read,$read1)");

print '<h3>Insert Multiple records</h3>';
if($insert){
    //return total inserted records using mysqli_affected_rows
    print 'Success! Total ' .$MySQLi_CON->affected_rows .' rows added.<br />'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $MySQLi_CON->errno .') '. $MySQLi_CON->error);
}

    ?>
```

**Errors:**

> Error : (1054) Unknown column 'sample123' in 'field list'

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  on your query. Pretty obvious here; unquoted strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot quotes at VALUES part, it should look like this :

```
$MySQLi_CON->query("INSERT INTO messages (user_from, user_to, title, message, date, user_from_read, user_to_read)
VALUES('$sample', '$orecip', '$otitle' ,'$omessage','$date','$read','$read1')");
```